# How to take a screenshot in iOS Simulator itself to get a full-page screenshot

Tags: ios-simulator, ios13

Is there a secret trick how to take a screenshot *in* the iOS Simulator itself?

I want to get the screenshot preview and be able to select full page screenshot like it's possible on a device running iOS 13 beta.

Comment: It seems this in not possible, feedback filled: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5056668693954560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was implemented in Xcode 11.4.

To get take the screenshot and get the preview click on `Device > Screenshot` or option (alt) + click on the screenshot button in the window title:

[image: triggering a screenshot in Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xcrun simctl io <UDID> screenshot ...` (check `xcrun simctl help io` for full details) to do this from the command line, or just save it from Simulator.app's File menu.

Comment: But that doesn't trigger the regular screenshot / full-page screenshot menu, does it? see: https://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-take-full-page-screenshots-in-ios-13-ipados-13/

Comment: Oh, I see what you are asking now, sorry.  No, that just dumps the framebuffer to disk.  We actually don't have an open radar/fba for this.  Could you file one?